# How to parse string into object?

Tags: javascript, parsing

### Background

I have a string containing a javascript object. This string is not JSON stringified ( only  a portion of  it is ).

I need to convert this string into an object so than I can use it.

Here is an example of such string:

```
`{method: 'POST', url: '/iot/pipe/', query: {}, body: { d: '{"n": "861359031087669", "b": 100, "v": "02.37", "t": 1, "d":[[1515070895,413973366,21717600,110,1,0],[1515070897,413975033,21719083,102,1,0]]}' }, headers: { host: 'node_session_iot', connection: 'close', 'content-length': '1219', accept: '*/*', 'user-agent': 'QUECTEL_MODULE', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }`
```

### `JSON.parse`

The string is not json stringified, so parse will fail.

### `eval`

`eval` is evil. Never use it.

### Solutions?

I find it incredibly frustrating. I have the object right in front of me and I can't do a single thing with it.
What other options do I have to convert this string into an object?

Comment: How can this be a String ? You have some double quotes in there that are breaking the whole String.

Comment: Maybe you can use regex expression to extract the info you need, then use the object constructor if available to get the object. Or remove the useless parts using regex as well then parse it?

Comment: What you have is a Javascript literal. You're not *supposed* to have those as a string; that's specifically what JSON is for, which is a *safe* subset of Javascript. You either need a *Javascript parser*, or you take the plunge and `evil` it. Preferably you could go back and not produce such strings in the first place.

Comment: @Zenoo Copy paste issue. The characters at begin and end should be ``` instead of `"`. Fixing.

Comment: @nespapu I spend the last hour of my life writting a parser only yo find out it produces ugly and unstable code. The problem with parsers is that any changes to the format of the string will completely obliterate the code.

Comment: @deceze I completely agree with you, but this is a task given to me. I have no power whatsoever on the type of input I am given ....

Comment: You can probably find existing Javascript parsers written in Javascript. As long as the string is *syntactically valid Javascript*, there's no reason it couldn't be parsed stably.

Comment: @deceze Could you provide an example of such a parser and how I could use it to solve this issue? I am looking at esprima right now but I still need to understand how to use it.

Comment: Yeah, depending on the library used, a parser would probably give you an abstract syntax tree, which you'd have to assemble into a usable object. Not a trivial task, but safe and stable. And no, I can't help you with an example here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I wont say it is a perfect solution and it is very example specific but idea is to convert string to step by step to JSON string

Hope it works

```
//take in quotation
y = x.replace(/(\w+)(\s*:)+/g,"\"\$1\"$2");
//convert single quotation into "
y = y.replace(/\'/g,"\"" );
// remove " from object literals
y = y.replace(/\"\s*{/g,"{" );
y = y.replace(/}\"\s*/g,"}" );
yOjb = JSON.parse(y);
```

Comment: Naive, but it works ! Amazing out of the box thinking !

Answer (score 0):

Your request body is in correct JSON format. 
So take request body from the given string by using regular expression or string functions and use JSON.Parse method to get the object.

In this case your request body is

```
{"n": "861359031087669", "b": 100, "v": "02.37", "t": 1, "d":[[1515070895,413973366,21717600,110,1,0],[1515070897,413975033,21719083,102,1,0]]}
```

Please see the below snapshot for the JSON.Parse function.
[image]

Comment: Yes, but if I do it that way, I literally loose access to all the other information....

Comment: If you can provide a regex to pick just the body of the expression, I will accept your answer.